# Multiple accessory checkmarks displayed on a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView that displays checkmarks when a row is selected. The problem is that when the table view scrolls multiple checkmarks are shown when only one was ever row selected. The problem arises as the table scrolls and the dequeue process occurs. Here's my cellForRowAtIndexPath: method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

        cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

        cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:204.0/255.0 green:56.0/255.0 blue:55.0/255.0 alpha:1];

    }

    // Get item from tableData
    NSDictionary *item = (NSDictionary *)[displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"key"];

    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Asap-Bold" size: 14.0f]];

    return cell;
}
```

and didSelect method:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    selectedCityTableString = cell.textLabel.text;

    cellAccessoryImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-tick.png"]] ;
    cellAccessoryNoneImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]] ;

    if (cell.accessoryType==UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {
        //        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        cell.accessoryView = cellAccessoryImageView;

        if (prev!=indexPath.row) {
            cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:prev inSection:0]];
            //cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            cell.accessoryView = cellAccessoryNoneImageView;

            prev=indexPath.row;
        }
    }
    else{
        //        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.accessoryView = cellAccessoryNoneImageView;

    }

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *mutCityStr = [[selectedCityTableString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"] lowercaseString];

   // NSString *mutCityStr = @"c";

    [prefs setObject:mutCityStr forKey:@"selectedCityTableString"];
    [prefs synchronize];

#ifdef DEBUG    
    NSLog(@"mutCityStr is %@",mutCityStr);
    NSLog(@"selectedCityTableString is %@",selectedCityTableString);
    NSLog(@"posting notification from TWO TABLES");
#endif

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TTSelectedList" object:selectedCountryTableString];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your .h file

```
int selectedRow;
```

In your .m file

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
        // your other code for cell init,etc
        int row = [indexPath row];
        cell.accessoryType = (row == selectedRow) ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        cell.textLabel.textColor= (row == selectedRow) ? [UIColor colorWithRed:242.0f/255.0f green:104.0f/255.0f blue:42.0f/255.0f alpha:1] : [UIColor blackColor] ;

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    selectedRow = [indexPath row];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 3):

Supposing you have a property (attribute) called `selectedRow` use the combination of this methods:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...

    if (indexPath.row == self.selectedRow) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // If there is a cell selected deselect
    if (self.selectedRow != NSNotFound) {
        NSIndexPath *previousIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.selectedAQIType inSection:0];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:previousIndexPath];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    // Select the touched cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    self.selectedRow = indexPath.row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView`'s delegate method `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` reuses the cell based on the reuseidentifier. Hence you need to reset the entire cell contents to default.

In your case uncheck the cell's view before you return the cell.

Comment: can you be more specific with  "uncheck the cell's view before you return the cell" thanks

Comment: Your question says that many rows are checked, so before you return the cell you need to reset the view. If you can post some code from didselectrowatindexpath, i can write what has to be reset. Also as @mrunal suggested you can maintain which rows are checked.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, store your selected row indexes in one *`NSArray`*. (in *`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`* method)

And in *`cellForRowAtIndexPath`* method, check whether *`indexPath.row`* is available in that array then enable your checkmark, else disable.

*Note: Maintain array for check-uncheck event*

Hope this will help you.